# How do you access to SAFE ARRAY in a VARIANT data type returned from a COM object in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, com, variant, safearray

I am working with a COM object. I Call a function of COM objects and this functin return VARIANT data type that contain SAFE ARRAY of my equipments list.
How can I work with this VARIANT to access to SAFEARRY of my equipments.

```
  VARIANT namList; 
  SAFEARRAY* myequip;
  namList=str->GetNames();
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/propvarutil/nf-propvarutil-varianttostringarray

Comment: @HansPassant It seems like there should be a cleanup required after calling `VariantToStringArray` or `VariantToStringArrayAlloc`, either to free allocated memory or to unlock the safearray. I don't see anything in the docs. Do you know what these methods do in memory?

Comment: @MichaelGunter - This library essentially targets PROPVARIANTs, and these utilities are for vectors (VT_VECTOR | VT_XXX), not SAFEARRAYs. You need to free the array and the strings returned from VariantToStringArrayAlloc and you must allocate the array yourself before calling VariantToStringArray and free the allocated strings.

Comment: @SimonMourier How do you free the memory returned from `VariantToStringArrayAlloc`? `CoTaskMemFree`? Is it sufficient to do this just for the array itself and not for the individual strings (i.e. are the items allocated contiguously with the array)? With `VariantToStringArray`, does one allocate only the memory for the array and let the function allocate the items? In which case, how do you clean up? If not, what's the expectation for the caller-allocated memory? Or am I misunderstanding all of this, and the string "array" is actually just a blob of strings back to back in memory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use a SAFEARRAY in a VARIANT like this, you need to do a lot of validation and error-checking. Here's the rough pattern you'll need to follow. Please read the comments carefully, as I have made some assumptions about the COM API that you're using.

```
// verify that it's an array
if (V_ISARRAY(&namList))
{
    // get safe array
    LPSAFEARRAY pSafeArray = V_ARRAY(&namList);

    // determine the type of item in the array
    VARTYPE itemType;
    if (SUCCEEDED(SafeArrayGetVartype(pSafeArray, &itemType)))
    {
        // verify it's the type you expect
        // (The API you're using probably returns a safearray of VARIANTs,
        // so I'll use VT_VARIANT here. You should double-check this.)
        if (itemType == VT_VARIANT)
        {
            // verify that it's a one-dimensional array
            // (The API you're using probably returns a one-dimensional array.)
            if (SafeArrayGetDim(pSafeArray) == 1)
            {
                // determine the upper and lower bounds of the first dimension
                LONG lBound;
                LONG uBound;
                if (SUCCEEDED(SafeArrayGetLBound(pSafeArray, 1, &lBound)) && SUCCEEDED(SafeArrayGetUBound(pSafeArray, 1, &uBound)))
                {
                    // determine the number of items in the array
                    LONG itemCount = uBound - lBound + 1;

                    // begin accessing data
                    LPVOID pData;
                    if (SUCCEEDED(SafeArrayAccessData(pSafeArray, &pData)))
                    {
                        // here you can cast pData to an array (pointer) of the type you expect
                        // (The API you're using probably returns a safearray of VARIANTs,
                        // so I'll use VARIANT here. You should double-check this.)
                        VARIANT* pItems = (VARIANT*)pData;

                        // use the data here.

                        // end accessing data
                        SafeArrayUnaccessData(pSafeArray);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much .Your response was so helpful.
Dimension of SAFFEARRAY is more than 1.In my example is 65262 how i can get element of this safearray?

Comment: @mahdiLotfi `SafeArrayGetDim` is returning `65262`? That seems highly unlikely. Double-check that you're passing in a correct `LPSAFEARRAY`.